# The problem of sensor_msgs::fillImage

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, robotino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I rosmake the robotino package and got the error "undefined reference to `sensor_msgs::fillImage". Any one has the idea how to solve it? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37634/the-problem-of-sensor_msgs::fillimage/) by [aricc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1727/aricc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aricc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1727/aricc/) on 2012-07-01**:
The ROS version is 1.8.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sensor_msgs::fillImage` is defined as an inline function in the header file `sensor_msgs/fill_image.h` in `/opt/ros/fuerte/include`. Are you sure that you are including it?

**Edit**: In a recent update, lib files for messages were removed. It could be that your cmake still tries to link against it. Try `make clean` before building your package. You can also use `rosmake --pre-clean`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1